# How to make Android Direct Reply Notification feature work in pre - Android N devices?

Tags: android, android-notifications, backwards-compatibility

I am trying to implement Android Direct Reply notification in my app. **I've managed to implement it successfully in Android N emulator**. But it is not working on Marshmallow devices. When I click on action button in notification the reply edittext is not showing in devices below Android N. I know this feature will work in pre Android N devices, as it is available in WhatsApp.

My question is how to make it work in pre Android N devices? I'm sharing my code here. Any help would be great. Thanks.

MainActivity

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.RemoteInput;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// Key for the string that's delivered in the action's intent.
public static final String KEY_TEXT_REPLY = "key_text_reply";
private static final int notificationID = 1234;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);




    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        startNotif();
        }
    });
}

private void startNotif() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReciever.class);
// use System.currentTimeMillis() to have a unique ID for the pending intent
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

    String replyLabel = "Reply";
    RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(KEY_TEXT_REPLY)
            .setLabel(replyLabel)
            .build();

    // Create the reply action and add the remote input.
    Notification.Action action =
            new Notification.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_send,
                    "Action", pIntent)
                    .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                    .build();

    // Build the notification and add the action.
    Notification newMessageNotification =
            new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_remove_circle_black_48dp)
                    .setContentTitle("Title")
                    .setContentText("Content")
                    .addAction(action).build();

// Issue the notification.
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(notificationID, newMessageNotification);
    }
}
```

NotificationReciever

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.RemoteInput;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * Created by User on 13-Jun-16.
 */
public class NotificationReciever extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Toast.makeText(this,getMessageText(getIntent()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private CharSequence getMessageText(Intent intent) {
        Bundle remoteInput = RemoteInput.getResultsFromIntent(intent);
        if (remoteInput != null) {
            return remoteInput.getCharSequence(MainActivity.KEY_TEXT_REPLY);
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,"Remoteinput is null",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find answers ?

Comment: @Prakash Ive tried everything but Direct reply didn't work on versions below Noughat. So as TommyChan said in below answer we will have to launch an activity that does what we want with direct reply like layout in it. I think that is how its done in whatsapp. Correct me if I'm wrong. :)

Comment: @SudheeshMohan I'm trying to implements the same thing. Can you please tell how you managed this issue, and what's the best solution that you have found?

Comment: Prior to N, it can be done via AndroidWear component hidden in notification of apps that supported replying from AndroidWear

Answer (score 2):

In the docs it tells you to not use a broadcast receiver or a service for api below N. So you'd have to launch an activity which does what you want and wrap it in a pending intent instead.

```
if (isDirectReplySupported) {
  return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
}
return PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: So the Whatsapp (below N) is actually launching an activity for replying instead of direct reply?

Comment: Most likely. In the activity they would have code that parses the intent and if a flag such as direct reply is there, will send off a message. This was the pattern for wear apps prior to N.